# How to output a new column in a SELECT query based on a condition?

Tags: sql, oracle

Currently, I have this SQL query:

```
SELECT AVG(ttbe.MarkGiven) FROM tblTestsTakenByEmployee ttbe
INNER JOIN tblCoursesTakenByEmployee ctbe ON ttbe.EmployeeId = ctbe.EmployeeId
LEFT JOIN tblCourse c ON ctbe.CourseId = c.CourseId
WHERE ctbe.HasCompletedCourse = 'Y'
GROUP BY ctbe.CourseId, c.CourseName, EXTRACT(YEAR FROM ctbe.DateOfCourseCompletion), ctbe.EmployeeId
```

At the moment, this returns the average mark of a single employee on a course which was completed on a certain year, calculated across each of the tests it contains (a course can have multiple tests).

I want to output an additional column to the SELECT query which specifies whether that employee has passed the course, based on a threshold. For example, if `AVG(ttbe.MarkGiven) >= 40` then it would return 'Y' in the new column, otherwise it would return 'N'. What's the simplest and most efficient way of achieving this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use the CASE expression like that:

```
SELECT AVG(ttbe.MarkGiven),
CASE WHEN AVG(ttbe.MarkGiven) >= 40 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END as exam_passed
FROM tblTestsTakenByEmployee ttbe
INNER JOIN tblCoursesTakenByEmployee ctbe ON ttbe.EmployeeId = ctbe.EmployeeId
LEFT JOIN tblCourse c ON ctbe.CourseId = c.CourseId
WHERE ctbe.HasCompletedCourse = 'Y'
GROUP BY ctbe.CourseId, c.CourseName, EXTRACT(YEAR FROM ctbe.DateOfCourseCompletion), 
ctbe.EmployeeId
```

[https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-basics/oracle-case/#:~:text=Oracle%20CASE%20expression%20allows%20you,that%20accepts%20a%20valid%20expression](https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-basics/oracle-case/#:%7E:text=Oracle%20CASE%20expression%20allows%20you,that%20accepts%20a%20valid%20expression).

Answer (score 0):

You could use your current query as a CTE and then from the CTE use the reulst and compare it to your threshold

The advantag of the CTE is that you will not have to recalculate your AVG(ttbe.MarkGiven)

```
   WITH _CTE as 
    (
        SELECT AVG(ttbe.MarkGiven) as Col1 
        FROM tblTestsTakenByEmployee ttbe
        INNER JOIN tblCoursesTakenByEmployee ctbe 
        ON ttbe.EmployeeId = ctbe.EmployeeId
        LEFT JOIN tblCourse c 
        ON ctbe.CourseId = c.CourseId
        WHERE ctbe.HasCompletedCourse = 'Y'
        GROUP BY ctbe.CourseId, c.CourseName, EXTRACT(YEAR FROM ctbe.DateOfCourseCompletion), ctbe.EmployeeId
    )
    Select  Col1
            ,CASE 
                WHEN Col1 >= 50 THEN 'Y' 
                ELSE 'N'
            END AS Col1_Threshold
```